# How can I remove drag event on one element in a draggable group?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a draggable group, and one element in that group have called click event. Now I want to remove drag event on that element. See http://jsfiddle.net/gLvyouct/1/

I have tried these methods:

- Add `circle.call(drag).on(".drag", null);`

  Not working and I don't why.
- Only call drag events on rects

  Will affect the fluency of drag events. Elements are shaking when being dragged.
- In definition of drag behavior `if (d3.event.sourceEvent.target.nodeName == "circle") return;`

  Not working. The group still moves when your mouse is on the edge of circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky one, because if you bind the drag event to the `rect` and then move the `g` that the rect belongs in, the calculated `dx` and `dy` values in the `d3.event` object will be messed up after each event fires, since those calculated values have been transformed into the local co-ordinate system of the element that the drag behaviour is bound to.  So, we can do something similar ourselves to work around this.  The trick here is knowing that we really just need to figure out the change in the `x` and `y` position of the mouse during the drag action. And that d3 makes these available in the `sourceEvent` property of the `d3.event` object.

So use the underlying `sourceEvent` in the `d3.event` object to get the `clientX` and `clientY` position and just calculate the difference between the last values and the current values, which will tell you how far extra you need to `translate` the `g` element.  You also need to initialise the values that you're comparing to so that you don't get a random jump at the start.  Luckily, we can use the `dragstart` event to do just that.

Once we've figured that out, we can then bind the `drag` handler to the `rect` and we should be good to go.

Here is an example doing exactly what I've described.

```js
var g = d3.select("#mysvg").append("g");
var rect = g.append("rect").attr("height", 100).attr("width", 100);
var circle = g.append("circle").attr("cx", 200).attr("cy", 200).attr("r", 50).attr("fill", "black");
var transX = 0, transY = 0;
var lastX = 0, lastY = 0;

var drag = d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", function() {
    transX += d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX - lastX;
    transY += d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY - lastY;
    g.attr("transform", "translate(" + transX + "," + transY + ")");
    lastX = d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX;
    lastY = d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY;
}).on("dragstart", function() {
    lastX = d3.event.sourceEvent.clientX;
    lastY = d3.event.sourceEvent.clientY;
});
rect.call(drag);

circle.on("click", function() { 
    var now_color = d3.select(this).attr("fill");
    if (now_color == "black")
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "green");
    else 
        d3.select(this).attr("fill", "black");
});

//circle.call(drag).on(".drag", null);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mysvg" height="800" width="800"></svg>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much. But if I want to bind brush to hundreds of elements in a group and disable the event on only a few elements. It seems that I have to use a for-loop to pick the elements I want to call brush on. It's not like d3-style. :(

Comment: you don't need a for loop, just use a d3 selection and call `.call(drag)` and it should be OK.